# Using Google's Distance matrix on server side

Tags: google-maps

I am developing a web application where I need to find the closest bus-stop from a users location and mark it on a map. I have the list of bus-stops on my server. I am using Google's Distance Matrix service which returns me the distance between my source and multiple bus
stops. Then, by comparing the distance i get the nearest bus-stop.

But this is all happening at client side. I wanted my server to do the
decision.

Is it possible for my server to directly communicate with the Google
maps server and get the distance?

Thanks

Comment: If one of these answers worked for you, please accept it so the question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you're going to display it on a Google Map in the end. Google has a set of [Maps related web services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html), one of which is the [distance matrix](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/), that can be called from the server.

Comment: The OP asked for it, but I'd think it is better to refactor the code so that the client is doing it. I think it would be easier (i.e. cheaper for the developer, because at serverside he must handle what the browser normally handles for him) and also faster as the client is doing the job (request to the google distance api etc.) in the meantime while the rest of page is loading.

Comment: The web service I link to is server side. The data can be called from the server and pushed back to the client And the distance matrix gives driving directions between different points, not as a crow flies distance, which would be really difficult to do in any other way, except using a similar service. Generally I agree, client side is better but I don't have enough information about why @shilpa is making this request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mysql take a look at [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrcontains) which are a little poor or if you are able to use postgresql spatial(postgis) is way better.
Also most databases have spatial extensions.